'where name not in' is based on the results of a previous query
I am attempting to gather two opposing lists, based on a WHERE-IN list. Sorry if the term isn't correct, but it'll at least be consistent though out the post.
WHERE name IN ('name1')

I have a select statement that tells if a name is listed in a DB using WHERE-IN.
-- working
SELECT name FROM name_list
WHERE name IN ('name1','name2','name3','name4')

This result tells me only the names that are from my WHERE-IN list that are in the name_list, which is the first half of what I want.
Next, I want to see what names from my WHERE-IN list are not in name_list. I tried using WHERE-NOT IN, but this gave me all names that are in name_list that are not in my WHERE-IN list.
-- NOT working
SELECT name FROM name_list
WHERE name NOT IN ('name1','name2','name3','name4')

I know some SQL basics, but all of the searches I've dealt with in the past are looking at results from items in a DB table, whereas I'm now looking for results that aren't in table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Limitation(s):
The format of 'name1','name2','name3','name4' is needed to be kept for any viable answer.
An example of desired output would be:
search result 1 (name found)
name1
name2
name4

search result 2 (name not found)
name3


Do you have sample data and expected results; that would help

Table value constructor

Here's a good answer using Table Value Constructor that should help guide. Similar to an "IN LIST" but slightly different format. You put this in your FROM clause to treat your list of values as a table. You could also push your in-list values into a temp table and construct your sql off of that as another option.

Create a temp table and insert names in the table from either csv file or using below Insert statement:
INSERT INTO temp_name_list (name) VALUES ('name1');
.
.
INSERT INTO temp_name_list (name) VALUES ('nameN');

and use below query to get the results :
select temp_nl.name 
From temp_name_list temp_nl
LEFT JOIN name_list nl 
on temp_nl.name=nl.name 
WHERE nl.name IS NULL;


due to the requirements of my organization, i must keep the names in the originally stated format of 'name1','name2','name3','name4'. this means that i cannot insert the names line-by-line as suggested by this answer.

Then you should add this requirement to the question and explain other "limitations"

This limitation makes things a bit hard, but let's assume you have some code placeholders that are replaced with a fixed string. Here's a really hacky workaround:
-- First result...
SELECT  name 
FROM    name_list
WHERE   name IN ('name1','name2','name3','name4')

-- Second result...
SELECT  REPLACE(ss.value, '''', '')
FROM    OPENJSON((
    SELECT  1 AS "'name1','name2','name3','name4'"
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    )) x
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(x.[key] COLLATE database_default, ',') ss
WHERE   NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT  1
        FROM    name_list nl
        WHERE   nl.name = REPLACE(ss.value, '''', '')
    )

To access the values in the 'name1', 'name2'...-string one have to create a dummy column, and then get back the name of it.
Due to T-SQL syntax, one needs to use "" quotes to wrap the ''-quotes.
Then, to get the value, I use OPENJSON, which allows easy pivoting without need to specify the columns ahead of time.
This gets back the string 'name1','name2','name3','name4' which then can be split into 4 chunks, and stripped of quotes by using STRING_SPLIT and REPLACE().
Finally, WHERE NOT EXISTS gets back the missing values.
This has some issue though, need quoted identifier set on, the string being searched can't have embedded commas and quotes, but otherwise it might work.
